# Shell script printing the most visited directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, directory

Is there a way to write a bash script with the following functionalities?

1. Be launched when I press some key or key combination. (not so important requirement)
2. Identify the 7 most visited directories in last 3 hours.
3. Offer me the list of this 7 directories so I can cycle through them with tab and shift-tab (backward). Then press enter would mean cd to the selected directory.

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "most visited directory"? visited by what?

Comment: my definition: Let's say that during 3 hours you call the cd command with 10 arguments (a1..a10) The directory `ax` is most visited if the command `cd ax` is called more often then cd ai, for each i in {a1, a10} where ax <> ai.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
#### cd history mechanism ##############################################

export CDHISTFILE=~/.cdhistory
if [ -e "$CDHISTFILE" ]
then
    cdht=`mktemp`
    tail -500 "$CDHISTFILE" > $cdht
    mv "$cdht" "$CDHISTFILE"
fi

function keep_cd_history() {
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then d="$HOME" ; else d="$1" ; fi
    cdhcan=`readlink -f "$d"`
    if 'cd' "$d"
    then
        echo -e `date +%s`"\t"$cdhcan >> $CDHISTFILE
    fi
}
function pick_cwd_from_history() {
    f=~/.cdhistgo
    cdhistpick "$f"
    if [ -r "$f" ] ; then cd "`head -1 $f`" ; fi
}

alias cd=keep_cd_history
alias cdh=pick_cwd_from_history

########################################################################
```

The first section truncates the cd history mechanism's custom history file if it's gotten bigger than 500 lines since the last time we looked at it. We can't use Bash's built-in history because it doesn't include timestamps, which you need in order to get the "in the last 3 hours" behavior.

The two Bash functions do things we cannot do in the Perl code below, which otherwise does all the heavy lifting.  The only tricky bit here is the `readlink` call, which canonicalizes the paths you use. We have to do that so that `cd $HOME ; cd ; cd ~ ; cd ../$USER` results in 4 instances of the same path in the `cd` history, not four different entries.

The aliases are just convenience wrappers for the functions.

Now the really tricky bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use List::Util qw(min);

#### Configurables #####################################################

# Number of seconds back in time to look for candidate directories
my $history_seconds_threshold = 3 * 60 * 60;

# Ignore directories we have gone to less than this many times
my $access_count_threshold = 1;

# Number of directory options to give in pick list
my $max_choices = 7;


#### DO NOT OPEN. NO USER-SERVICEABLE PARTS INSIDE. ####################

# Get file name our caller wants the cd choice to be sent to
die "usage: $0 <choice_file>\n" unless $#ARGV == 0;
my $cdhg_file = $ARGV[0];
unlink $cdhg_file;      # don't care if it fails

# Build summary stats from history file to find recent most-accessed
my $oldest_interesting = time - $history_seconds_threshold;
my %stats;
open my $cdh, '<', "$ENV{HOME}/.cdhistory" or die "No cd history yet!\n";
while (<$cdh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($secs, $dir) = split /\t/;
    next unless $secs and $secs >= $oldest_interesting;
    ++$stats{$dir};
}

# Assemble directory pick list
my @counts = sort values %stats;
$access_count_threshold = $counts[$max_choices - 1] - 1
        if @counts > $max_choices;
my @dirs = grep { $stats{$_} > $access_count_threshold } keys %stats;
$max_choices = min($max_choices, scalar @dirs);

# Show pick list, and save response to the file pick_cwd_from_history()
# expects.  Why a file?  The shell must call chdir(2), not us, because
# if we do, we change only our CWD.  Can't use stdio; already in use.
my $choice;
if ($max_choices > 1) {
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $max_choices; ++$i) {
        print $i + 1, '. ', $dirs[$i], "\n";
    }
    print "\nYour choice, O splendid one? [1-$max_choices]: ";
    $choice = <STDIN>;
    chomp $choice;
    exit 0 unless $choice =~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $choice <= $max_choices;
}
elsif ($max_choices == 1) {
    print "Would you like to go to $dirs[0]? [y/n]: ";
    $choice = 1 if uc(<STDIN>) =~ /^Y/;
}
else {
    die "Not enough cd history to give choices!\n";
}
if ($choice) {
    open my $cdhg, '>', $cdhg_file or
            die "Can't write to $cdhg_file: $!\n";
    print $cdhg $dirs[$choice - 1], "\n";
}
```

Save this to a file called `cdhistpick`, make it executable, and put it somewhere in your `PATH`. You won't execute it directly. Use the `cdh` alias for that, as it passes in a necessary argument via `pick_cwd_from_history()`.

How does it work? Ummmm, exercise for the reader? :)

To get your first requirement, the hotkey, you can use any macro recording program you like for your OS of choice. Just have it type `cdh` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for you. Or, you can run `cdh` yourself, since it's easy to type.

If you want a simpler but less functional alternative that will work everywhere, get into the habit of using Bash's reverse incremental search feature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. Press that, then type "cd " (without the quotes, but with the trailing space) to be taken back to the previous `cd` command. Then each time you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, it takes you back to the `cd` command prior to that. In this way, you can walk backwards through all the `cd` commands you've given, within the limits of Bash's history feature.

Say:

```
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

to see how many command lines Bash history will store for you. You might need to increase this to hold 3 hours worth of command history.

To search forward through your command history after having stepped backwards through it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

If that doesn't work on your system, it is likely due to a conflict with [software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control). You can fix it with this command:

```
$ stty stop undef
```

That prevents Ctrl-S from being interpreted as the XOFF character.

The consequence of this is that you can then no longer press Ctrl-S to temporarily pause terminal output. Personally, the last time I used that on purpose was back in the days of slow modems. These days with fast scrolling and big scroll-back buffers, I only use this feature by accident, then have to spend a second remembering to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to get the terminal un-stuck. :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this great use of history command. I will use it and if that's insufficient I will try to implement the timestamps.

Comment: Can I go to forward too in history?

Comment: This would be good for the following situation: I press Ctrl+R, then cd, then Ctrl+R 10 times (I'm doing it quickly) and I will note that I was too quick and want to go one step back.

Comment: It does for me (bash 4.1.5 on Debian squeeze or 3.2.39 on Debian lenny or 4.1.7 on OpenBSD, started with `HOME=/none bash`).

Comment: Found the problem and fix, so added it to above and deleted my comments.

Comment: Great! Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this script](https://raw.github.com/dilawar/Scripts/master/cd.sh). You need to install `sqlite3` for using it. It launches sqlite3 in subshell to update the database (so that changing to directory is as fast as with normal `cd`). Download this script is `source` it in your `.bashrc`. Use command `c` to change to directories. If no argument is given to `c` then a sorted list of directories most accessed in last two days will be displayed on bash. You can pick one.